# Как красиво выровнять? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Есть проблема: нужно выровнять блок с display: inline-block по середине. Почему-то свойство margin: 0 auto не помогло. Все на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

form::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
    <label for="">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="">Логин</label>
    <input type="text" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для inline-block'а:

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto
  background: lightblue;
}

form::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
<form action="">
    <div>
        <label for="">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="">Логин</label>
        <input type="text" required>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Но зачем Вы задаете inline-block для формы? Не проще сделать ее блоком и выравнивать с помощью того же margin: 0 auto?

Comment: Ну мне нужно маленькое окошко регистрации, а так получается растянутый на весь экран блок  @Вадим

Comment: Задать ей фиксированную ширину

Comment: @Dmitry_Maesnes задайте не фиксированную ширину, а `max-width`, вместо `width`, чтобы было адаптивно

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div class="wraper-form">
<form action="">
    <div>
        <label for="">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="">Логин</label>
        <input type="text" required>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

```
.wraper-form{
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto
  background: lightblue;
}

form::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

P.S.: адаптива не хочешь?

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Чтобы задавая ширину 200px, она была реально 200px */

form {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

form input:not(:first-child) { /* Всем input в form, которые не первый элемент */
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Логин" required>
</form>
```